# SF movie live action - dystopian world, couple gets rescued by a spaceship with a huge eye run by an android butler

Tags: story-identification, movie, dystopia, androids

Probably from the 80s or early 90s.

Dystopian world where if you weren't upper class you were basically a slave for work; men and women kept separate.

One couple who met secretly are about to be captured and executed for being together, when a spaceship with a huge eye on the side appears and offers them refuge. They decide they have nothing to lose, so they get in.

The ship is run by an android who takes the form of a butler IIRC, and is rather clueless about humans, but tries to accommodate them. At one point, they ask for a bed, and after they describe what that is, the butler presents them with a perfectly nice bed, in the middle of a stream.

Eccentric, but I have fond memories and would love to see it again if anyone recognizes this.

Comment: Did you actually watch this in the '90s or later? If later, then when?

Comment: Watched it in the mid to late 90s, IIRC